# Intervention error in Google Chrome Console

Tags: google-chrome, dom, console, warnings

Am getting this on chrome console. Is it an error in my code or browser related issue?

```
[Intervention] Slow network is detected. See <URL> for more details.
Fallback font will be used while loading: <URL>
```

Comment: This is the most obnoxious "feature" Chrome has built in a long time. I don't even mind the fact that fonts are being replaced etc, but 90% of the time it's "detecting" a slow network while I'm on fiber or localhost, and now it's polluting the console log with nasty red errors nearly every single page load. It's horrendous.

Answer (score 0):

This isnt a error in your code and is specific to Chrome and how it determines a slow network. Nothing to worry about and you can even remove the warning in pre-Chrome v63:
chrome://flags/#enable-webfonts-intervention-v2

Unfortunately havent figured out how to do it in the latest chrome yet...